# R for loops with if clauses - possible in dplyr?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, break

My data (tmpH) is a series of time points (of blood samplings), and I want to add a column of 0s and 1s to show if two time point are sufficiently distant. For this I start by making

`mutate(dT = difftime(time,lag(time),units="days"))`

And set the first dT = 0.

Say we will allow sampling every two days, and we observe samples on days 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 and 11. Then the samples from days 1, 3, 5, 8 and 11 are OK (allow = 1), but those from days 2, 4 and 6 could/should have been canceled (allow = 0). For the first sample (day 1) I set allow = 1 using

`mutate(allow = ifelse(dT == 0,1,0))`

and then the plan is to set allow = 1 when two days have passed since the initial sample. And go on like that until the end of the list.

I hope that's clear!

Small data sample (times, dT, allow from one patient):

```
  time                       dT allow
  <dttm>                  <dbl> <dbl>
1 2018-12-31 23:01:11     0         1
2 2019-01-01 09:26:32     0.434     0
3 2019-01-02 09:40:55     1.01      0
4 2019-01-03 12:18:36     1.11      0
5 2019-01-04 12:28:37     1.01      0
6 2019-04-24 19:26:18   110.        0
```

Here, allow should be 1 in rows 1, 4 and 6.

Now how to do that in R? I'm a big dplyr fan and consider myself fairly adept, but for this I had to build a complicated nested for beast with a few if clauses:

```
for (r in 1:nrow(tmpH)) {
   if (tmpH$allow[r] == 1) {
      for (r2 in (r+1):nrow(tmpH)) {
         if (r+1 <= nrow(tmpH)) {
            if (sum(tmpH$dT[(r+1):r2]) >= 2) {
               tmpH$allow[r2] <- 1
               break
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

To make matters worse I also have to do this by tibble group (patient).

Any suggestions to do this in dplyr/less complicated/less resource heavy? I get stack usage errors... Also, the break is very important and I can't find any indication that that's possible in dplyr.

Crossing fingers...

/Jens

Comment: Paste a sample of your data by doing `dput(head(tmpH)` and include that in your original question so that people have something to work on.

Comment: Updated, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr::accumulate()`.

I used this dataset:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(patient = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), time = c("2018-12-31_23:01:11", "2019-01-01_09:26:32", 
"2019-01-02_09:40:55", "2019-01-03_12:18:36", "2019-01-04_12:28:37", 
"2019-04-24_19:26:18", "2018-12-31_23:01:11", "2019-01-01_09:26:32", 
"2019-01-02_09:40:55", "2019-01-03_12:18:36", "2019-01-04_12:28:37", 
"2019-04-24_19:26:18"), dt = c(0, 0.434, 1.01, 1.11, 1.01, 110, 
0, 0.434, 1.01, 1.11, 1.01, 110), allow = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

As Andrew told you, this is the right way to share your dataset so we can load it easily.

Here is the help of `accumulate()`:

> ```
> accumulate() sequentially applies a 2-argument function to elements of
> a vector. Each application of the function uses the initial value or
> result of the previous application as the first argument. The second
> argument is the next value of the vector.
> ```

We want to use `accumulate()` on the column `dt` and apply to each row a function that will take 2 arguments: `y` is the current row value of `dt`and `x` is the previous row value of `dt`.

If the function only returns `x+y`, this will be the exact same as if we used `cumsum()`. However, by using `ifelse()` we can make it so the cumulative sum restarts whenever it is greater than 2. You then only have to set allow to 1 if our custom cumsum is equal to 0.

Here is the code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    group_by(patient) %>% 
    mutate(
        dt_cumsum=accumulate(dt, function(x,y) if_else(x+y>=2, 0, x+y)), 
        allow2=ifelse(dt_cumsum==0,1,0)
    )
#> # A tibble: 12 x 6
#> # Groups:   patient [2]
#>    patient time          dt allow dt_cumsum allow2
#>    <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 A       23:01:11   0         1     0          1
#>  2 A       09:26:32   0.434     0     0.434      0
#>  3 A       09:40:55   1.01      0     1.44       0
#>  4 A       12:18:36   1.11      0     0          1
#>  5 A       12:28:37   1.01      0     1.01       0
#>  6 A       19:26:18 110         0     0          1
#>  7 B       23:01:11   0         1     0          1
#>  8 B       09:26:32   0.434     0     0.434      0
#>  9 B       09:40:55   1.01      0     1.44       0
#> 10 B       12:18:36   1.11      0     0          1
#> 11 B       12:28:37   1.01      0     1.01       0
#> 12 B       19:26:18 110         0     0          1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Note that you could also have written `accumulate(dt, ~if_else(.x+.y>=2, 0, .x+.y))` (lambda function) instead of the anonymous function.

Comment: That's spot on! Thank you so much!
What does the ~ do in front of if_else?¨

Comment: @JensMunk This is a lambda-function, very used with `purrr`. See more on that here: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/articles/other-langs.html

Comment: sorry no, still don't grasp ~.

Comment: @JensMunk better now?

Comment: It's clearer, but I'm still fascinated! :)